# *.pyをcx_Freezeでexe化したファイルのエラーについて

Tags: python, python3, cx-freeze

pythonファイルをcx_Freezeでexe化し、実行すると、以下のエラーが発生します。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MIHY\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_
Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Users\MIHY\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_
Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\MIHY\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mat
plotlib\__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
    from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like, mplDeprecation, dedent, get_lab
el
  File "C:\Users\MIHY\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mat
plotlib\cbook.py", line 32, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\MIHY\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\num
py\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\MIHY\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\num
py\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\MIHY\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\num
py\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\MIHY\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\num
py\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\MIHY\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\num
py\core\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "C:\Users\MIHY\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\num
py\core\numeric.py", line 1820, in <module>
    from .arrayprint import array2string, get_printoptions, set_printoptions
  File "C:\Users\MIHY\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\num
py\core\arrayprint.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .fromnumeric import ravel
  File "C:\Users\MIHY\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\num
py\core\fromnumeric.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import _methods
ImportError: cannot import name '_methods'
```

setup.pyは次のとおりです。

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os

base = None
exe = Executable(script = 'test.py',  base = base)

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\MIHY\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\MIHY\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\tcl\\tk8.6"

 # セットアップ
setup(name = 'test',
      version = '0.1',
      description = 'converter',
      executables = [exe])
```

---

なお、次の３つのライブラリーをインポートしています。

```
from mpmath import mp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
```

setup.pyに原因があると思うのですが、どのように修正すればよいか教えていただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 参考: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41959860

Comment: 参考リンクありがとうございます。次のようにpythonファイル記述することで解決しました。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　from mpmath import mp
import matplotlib
matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
'C:\\Users\\MIHY\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\mpl-data\\matplotlibrc'
matplotlib.use("Agg")  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy.core._methods
import numpy.lib.format

Comment: @MIHY お疲れ様です。もしお時間あれば[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)をお願いできませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

参考リンクありがとうございます。次のようにpythonファイル記述することで解決しました。

```
from mpmath import mp
import matplotlib
matplotlib.matplotlib_fname() 'C:\\Users\\MIHY\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\Lib\‌​\site-packages\\matp‌​lotlib\\mpl-data\\ma‌​tplotlibrc' matplotlib.use("Agg") 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv 
import numpy.core._methods 
import numpy.lib.format
```